# Can't find ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator

Tags: java, osgi, logback

I have an OSGI application I'm trying to start up, and I'm getting this error message:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve ch.qos.logback.classic [127](R 127.0): missing requirement [ch.qos.logback.classic [127](R 127.0)] osgi.serviceloader; (osgi.serviceloader=ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator) Unresolved requirements: [[ch.qos.logback.classic [127](R 127.0)] osgi.serviceloader; (osgi.serviceloader=ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator)]
```

I have the Aries project bundles installed, to provide the ServiceLoader compatability, so I'm a bit confused by the `osgi.serviceloader` requirement. Is this a LogBack specific service loader that I need to install?